# TaskJuggler, how to allocate limited resources for one-off task?

Tags: pm-software, product-management

I have a taskjuggler project.  During the "meat" of the work, the entire team can work on this only a limited number of hours per period (using day here for convenience).  I accomplish this with the `limit { dailymax 2h }` attribute for those resources.  However, there is one particular task (a conference), limited in duration, that will require a particular team member's undivided attention during that timeframe.

Is it possible to absolutely dedicate said team member to this task, full-time, ignoring any previously imposed limits?  This is what I have so far, and it does not work:

```
task conference "Conference" {
  start 2024-07-23
  #end   2024-07-26
  effort 4d
  priority 1000
  allocate pi
  limit { dailymax 8h }
  charge 2000 onend
}
```

How can I define this task for an exact set of days, an exact amount of effort, for an exact resource?